coupled eigenvalue problem with two eigenvalues
how can I find solutions ($\omega_i$ and $\mathbf{v}$) for a system which looks like this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{v} =\omega_1 \mathbf{v}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
A_3 & A_4 
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{v} =\omega_2 \mathbf{v}$$
Is there any theory for such systems or symplifications? Im a particulary interested in $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$.
Thanks

In this case are the $A_i$ matrices or numbers?

No, the A_i are matrices themselof size (n x n). The vector v is of size (4n x 1).

Let $\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix}$, and let $I$ be the indentity matrix.

$\boxed{\text{If } \omega_1 \ne 0 \text{ and } \omega_2 \ne 0}$:
Then the only solution is $\boxed{\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}}$, since the column vectors of the first and second matrix point in perpendicular directions. To see this algebraically, the proof is:
From the first matrix equation
$$\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix} =\omega_1 \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix}\\
\leftrightarrow &\begin{cases}
(A_1-\omega_1 I)\mathbf{v}_1 + A_2\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0} \\
-\omega_1 I \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0}
\end{cases}\\
\stackrel{\omega_1 \ne 0}{\rightarrow} &\ \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}$$
And from the second matrix equation
$$\begin{align*}
&\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
A_3 & A_4 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix} =\omega_2 \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix}\\
\leftrightarrow &\begin{cases}
-\omega_2 I \mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{0} \\
A_3\mathbf{v}_1 + (A_4-\omega_2 I)\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0}
\end{cases}\\
\stackrel{\omega_2 \ne 0}{\rightarrow} &\ \mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}$$
Therefore $\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1 \\ \mathbf{v}_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{0}$.

$\boxed{\text{If } \omega_1 \ne 0 \text{ and } \omega_2 = 0}$:
Then the first implication still holds, so $\boxed{\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0}}$, and the second equation simplifies to
$$\begin{align*}
A_3 \mathbf{v}_1 + A_4 \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0} \\
A_3 \mathbf{v}_1 + A_4 \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0} \\
\boxed{A_3 \mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{0}} \\
\end{align*}$$
And the solutions for $\mathbf{v}_1$ are the solutions of the above homogeneous system of linear equations, which can be solved by Gaussian elimination.

$\boxed{\text{If } \omega_1 = 0 \text{ and } \omega_2 \ne 0}$:
Then the second implication still holds, so $\boxed{\mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{0}}$, and the first equation simplifies to
$$\begin{align*}
A_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + A_2 \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0} \\
A_1 \mathbf{0} + A_2 \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0} \\
\boxed{A_2 \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{0}} \\
\end{align*}$$
And the solutions for $\mathbf{v}_2$ are the solutions of the above homogeneous system of linear equations, which can be solved by Gaussian elimination.

$\boxed{\text{If } \omega_1 = 0 \text{ and } \omega_2 = 0}$:
Then $\mathbf{v}$ is a solution if and only if it solves both of these homogeneous linear systems:
$$
\boxed{\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{v} =\mathbf{0}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
A_3 & A_4 
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{v} =\mathbf{0}}
$$
Both of which can be solved with Gaussian elimination.

Thanks a lot for this well understandable and long explanation. It helps a lot :)

Is the first case also true for $\omega_1 =\omega_2$? Cant i add both equations together and end up in a normal eignvalue problem?

Adding up the two equations isn't equivalent to the original equation. For example, if you add up
$$
\sin(x) + y = 1 \
-\sin(x) + y = 1
$$
Then you'd get $2y = 2$, whose solution is $y = 1$. But the solution of the original system is $x=k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}, y=1$.

Or maybe an even better example: Splitting the equation
$$x+y=0$$
Into
$$
x=0 \
y=0
$$
yield completely different solutions.

Ok. I understand. Is there any possibility to solve the following system of equations instead?   $$\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 (\omega_1 -\omega_2) & A_2 (\omega_1-\omega_2) \
A_3 (\omega_2-\omega_1)& A_4 (\omega_2-\omega_1)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 &\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1 v_1 \
\omega_2 v_2
\end{pmatrix}$$ Here the matrices $A_i$ are functions of $\omega_i-\omega_j$. $A_i\in C^{n\times n}$ and $v_i\in C^n$

I think it's best to post that as a separate question, so other people could also see it. @ZaraReinm.
